# Extrapolating survey results for a larger data set

Tags: survey, excel, extrapolation

I have a set of survey results in Excel for a sample of "customers" which asks for their income. This is chosen from defined ranges such as "Less than 10k", "10k to 15k", "16 to 20k", etc. The sample was approx 11% of the whole customer database. I wish to extrapolate this to the larger customer set and find what the average income of all customers is likely to be.

Is there a straightforward method to extrapolate the results? So far I've only placed arbitrary values to each income bracket (1,2,3 for each sequential category) and then used a Median and Average function.

TIA

CJ Sohal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical multiclass classification problem. I assume than you have some specific details of the costumers, such as gender, age, occupation, place they live (province/city/area). Then you can develop a classification model.
If the model developed has a good prediction power (F1, precision, etc.) then you can generalize your model to other 89% of your data; however, I personally don't like to develop/use such a model to use only 11% of data.

If you don't have any specific details of the customers, the only way to extrapolate is to use the ratio of the responses you have with regards to that 11% of data you have (***count(response A) divided by count(all responses)***). For example: 0.3 (30%) for "Less than 10k",  0.2 for "10k to 15k", etc., and then randomly pick costumers in the remaining 89% part and mark 30% as "Less than 10k" and so on.